How does the CoqIDE Shortcuts panel work?
Could somebody explain how to use the Windows CoqIDE-Edit-Preferences-Shortcuts panel?
Lacking any documentation, I've been trying the various buttons "Ctrl", "Shift", etc. and see what happens but it's a rather ineffective way to find out what gets modified.
Addition
Is there any way to reset settings? Playing with the Shortcuts panel finally has spoiled some basic functionality.
Thank you for any help.
